# How to generate various combinations of a string?

Tags: java, string

I have to generate a sequence of strings combination starting with some fixed bits at the beginning, for example,

```
String password = "abc-----"
```

Here, the first three characters remain the same for every combination, only the characters after that have to change,
I need various combinations of this string like

```
abca
abcb
abcc
-----
abcaa
abcab
---- so on
```

using any loop, so that within the same loop i need to compare this with other input string and output the string, if both match.

How to generate this sequence or various combinations of strings using a loop in Java or in general ?

//update, sorry, i forgot to post what i tried:

i am doing it using nested for loops such as,

```
for(char i='a'; i<'z'; i++) {
     for(char j='a'; j<'z'; j++) {
         String password = "abc" + i + j ;
         }
      }
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried and where exactly you got stuck

Comment: [permutation](http://crunchify.com/how-to-find-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-java-example/) of string will be fit for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to generate a random string then you can use: (here i have included numbers also in my random string generation, if you dont want to use numbers then you can remove from sample variable)

```
public String getRandomString(String prefix, int length) {
    String sample = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(prefix);

    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        sb.append(sample.charAt(random.nextInt(sample.length())));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```